# how to use Decay_function with Elastica?

Tags: elastica

I have a question on how to query the code below using Elastica?:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/hotels/_search/' -d '{
  "query": {
"function_score": {
    "functions": [
        {
            "DECAY_FUNCTION": {
                "price": {
                    "origin": "0",
                    "scale": "20"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "DECAY_FUNCTION": {
                "location": {
                    "origin": "11, 12",
                    "scale": "2km"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "properties": "balcony"
        }
    },
   `` "score_mode": "multiply"
}
```

}
}'

Hope someone can lend me an arm here.

Thanks,